# Changing existing script for Finding Duplicates in Google Sheets and entering "yes" in the last column instead of coloring it

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I am new here and have no idea what I am doing. I found a script online and thought it would work for what I needed, but I would like to change it some. Any help would be appreciated. I have already changed it a little. If it would help to share the form with someone I can do that since it is only in the testing stages.

What I am wanting to do is instead of coloring the duplicates red in the main sheet I want it to put "Yes" in the last column of the main sheet. I would also like it to ignore the blank rows. Is this possible? (I copied the script I am currently using below)

```
function findDuplicates() {
  // List the columns you want to check by number (A = 1)
  var CHECK_COLUMNS = [13];

  // Get the active sheet and info about it
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("USE THIS SHEET FOR DATA").activate();
  var numRows = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var numCols = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();

  // Create the temporary working sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet("FindDupes");

  // Copy the desired rows to the FindDupes sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < CHECK_COLUMNS.length; i++) {
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,CHECK_COLUMNS[i],numRows);
    var nextCol = newSheet.getLastColumn() + 1;
    sourceRange.copyTo(newSheet.getRange(1,nextCol,numRows));
  }

  // Find duplicates in the FindDupes sheet and color them in the main sheet
  var dupes = false;
  var data = newSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (i = 1; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i+1; j < data.length; j++) {
      if  (data[i].join() == data[j].join()) {
        dupes = true;
        sourceSheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,numCols).setFontColor("red");
        sourceSheet.getRange(j+1,1,1,numCols).setFontColor("red");

      }
    }
  }

  // Remove the FindDupes temporary sheet
  ss.deleteSheet(newSheet);

  // Alert the user with the results
  if (dupes) {
    Browser.msgBox("Possible duplicate(s) found and colored red.");
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox("No duplicates found.");
  }
};
```

Comment: Yep it's possible. We all learned to code too, so you are not excused from learning just because you're starting out. For methods available to the Spreadsheet class, you'll want to review the Apps Script API documentation. You should also learn about how `if` statements work in Javascript, and JS comparison operators. Often when starting out it is helpful to write the whole program yourself, rather than try to shoehorn your desired behavior into a possibly incompatible method. E.g., start by just writing a function that will write a value to the sheet, then make that a conditional write, etc.